# grep multi-value string at the end of line

Tags: r

I am using Rstudio. Understand "grep("T$",names(Text9))" means "give me those in vector Text9 the names of which end with the letter T.

Now I want to find those the names of which end with ABT or WABT. How to do it? Thank you.

Comment: grep("T$ | ABT$ | WABT$ ", names(Text9))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `grep` with the pattern `W?ABT$`:

```
grep("W?ABT$", names(Text9))
```

### Demo